# Twitter bootstrap typeahead multiple ID values on typeahead:selected?

Tags: javascript, typeahead.js

I'm using Twitter bootstrap typeahead on my web site.

Have an input "A" autosuggestion and an hidden input "B" to get ID when I click on a line in the autosuggestion of input "A"

The problem is that I have same data on json :

id: 1
firstname: sebastien
lastname: renard

id: 8
firstname: sebastien
lastname: renard

and when I select one of this 2 suggestion (on input "A"), the value on my hidden input "B" is : 1,8

I want only the ID of the selected suggestion on input "B", like this "1" and not "1,8".

Here is my javascript code :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
// globalSearch
var resultList, d;
$('input.form-control').typeahead({    
    name: 'typeahead',
 valueKey: 'id' ,
    remote: {
      url: 'sql/sql_globalSearch.php?query=%QUERY',
      filter: function(data) {
        d = data;
        resultListFull = data.map(function(item) {
          return item.prenom+' '+item.nom+', '+item.age+' ans, '+item.ville+' ('+item.dpt+')';
        });
        resultList = data.map(function(item) {
          return item.prenom+' '+item.nom;
        });
        resultID = data.map(function(item) {
          return item.id;
        });
        return resultListFull;
      }
    }   
}).on('typeahead:selected typeahead:autocompleted', function(ev, suggestion) {
 //$('input.form-control').val(resultList);
 $('input.globalSearchID').val(resultID);
});
//End globalSearch
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Rechercher une personne...." name="globalSearch" id="globalSearch"><input type="hidden" class="globalSearchID" name="globalSearchID" id="globalSearchID">
```

Could you please help me to solve this issue ?

Kind regards,

Sebastien